# PrimeNG styles are not applied when used with @tailwind base;

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, primeng

I am working on a project using Angular and Tailwind and recently we decided to add PrimeNG to take advantage of some of the components they have. However, we realized that styles are not applied even though they are included in angular.json.
When we remove our "@tailwind base;" config, then PrimeNG styles are applied. However, we need to configure our styles with @tailwind base;

Any idea on how to make PrimeNG styling work as expected when @tailwind base config is also in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use both `PrimeNG` and `tailwind` at the same time, you will face naming conflicts which will lead to undefined behavior,
To avoid this, use the [prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) option in your `tailwind.config.js` file

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

And now you must use the prefix `tw-` before the class name of tailwind-css which wont break any of your existing styles.

Comment: Would there by any other way? We have lots of files already. It would be extremely tedious to go over each file and update the styles

Comment: no, only 2 ways. first - delete @tailwind base, second is prefix. but it's a good idea to write a regexp to replace classNames with tw- at start

Answer (score 1):

A possibily can also be disable the tailwind preflight in your tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
};
```